# Access 2007- #Name? Error

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I am trying to specify a controlsource. I basically just create a text field in a report, use the build tool to find the relevant field from a subreport/query, and then set it. I know the path is right for the control source because I am not typing it myself, I am selecting it.

The field I am referencing still exists and is actually located where the controlsource is pointing. But for some reason, I get this error. It doesn't make sense.

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try naming the control differently from source name. For example, if you have field in the source called "Name", give the control name "Name_Textbox". Just to make sure you have two different names (source vs. control). I think I had these problems in previous versions of MS Access (e.g. 2003).

Answer (score 0):

I've seen that error (long time ago) and managed to fix it, IIRC, by wrapping the fully qualified name in brackets, e.g. [source table].[column  name].  Something to try at any rate.