# Access 2007 #Name? error - previous answer doesn't work for me

Tags: ms-access-2007

I'm having a similar issue as in the previous asked post. Thing is the answer doesn't work for me.

[Old post link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6587788/access-2007-name-error)

[image]

I have:

```
Coverage:  Coverage  
Control Source: =[Analyst Data 2013 Query1]![Coverage]
```

As per the previous answer I tried changing the control:

```
Coverage: Coverage_txt
Control Source: =[Analyst Data 2013 Query1]![Coverage]
```

But this still produces the error for me. Any time I try to link a field to a control source it doesn't work on any form/table/query/anywhere.

Please advise.

**EDIT**: Added screenshot at the top

Comment: Please return to the previous post and use that for the question.  Delete this post.

Comment: What do you mean? I can't comment on it. I think because it's very old.

Comment: Ah yea I included the link now. The old post isn't my own. Just one with the same name.

Comment: Any success with this?

Comment: I think it doesn't work fundamentally unless you have object dependency, e.g. you created the query/form from the source. You can't just source from something independent.

Comment: No.  It works solely by name references.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Coverage: Coverage_txt
Control Source: =[Analyst Data 2013 Query1]![Coverage_txt]
```

I think you mean that `Coverage_txt` is the name of the field in a form called `Analyst Data 2013 Query1`.  So, the binding will have to use the name of the field, not the name of the data source.

**General approach (since above did not work):**  The syntax for binding fields can be tricky.  Try to get another field from the other form to appear -- ANY field.  If you can, the issue is field naming; if you can't, maybe it's the name of the form.

You can have the names correct and still struggle with syntax.  [Here is a good resource](http://access.mvps.org/access/forms/frm0031.htm) for handling parent-child relationships (sub-forms, sub-reports).

**Extra advice:**  I suggest you pick a better name for the form.  Spaces in names for Access objects are a bad practice -- they lead to trouble.  Also, `Query1` is not descriptive, so I wonder if there is a better name that says something about the result.  Going back and renaming objects in Access is a big hassle, so it's important to name things as well as you can.

Comment: Tried it, didn't work. You're right about the naming. I'll name is something more relevant/recognizable. The query has the column: Coverage. So I need the field to be populated with that. One work around I found is if I create a form directly from a query. In this case I just pressed "Form Design" when creating this customized form. Reason why the first method can't work here is because I'm trying to take something from this query1 and then query2.

Comment: I added a screenshot at the top. Tell me if you can't see it.

Comment: I think it is something fundamental with access that's not letting me apply the bindings.

Comment: I see above that you say you tried `[Analyst Data 2013 Query1]![Coverage]`.  What I suggested is `[Analyst Data 2013 Query1]![Coverage_txt]`. ...?

Comment: I've completed that form a while ago using dependencies and multiple forms. I'm working on a new form now and it's not working again.