# Using Date() works in Access 2007, but not with Access 2007 Runtime. Gives #Name?

Tags: ms-access

I have an unbound text box on a report using(tested both):
`=Format(Date(),"Medium Date") or =Format(Date(),"dd/mm/yyyy")`
as the control source.

This works fine in a Win 7 PC having Access 2007, but when these reports are created on a certain Win 10 PC using Access 2007 Runtime, it displays #Name?.
Another Win 10 PC using Access 2007 runtime displays the correct date format.

There are no table fields in the record source named Date. The Region settings in all PCs are identical.

Any advice greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I visited a site that spoke on this topic:
http://www.utteraccess.com/forum/name-error-date-t1492442.html

From what I understand, it could be that the column in your database table is called "Date" and that is interfering with the function Date().

It could also be that you're missing a library that defines the Date() function. See below quote I pulled from the site I linked earlier.

> It could be that you're missing a library that defines that function called Date(). Open any VBA code window and click Tools > References and see if any of the libraries listed say "MISSING" in front of them. If one does, UNcheck it and check something similar to it down the list of library names below.

This similar question was answered here:
[Access 2007- #Name? Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6587788/access-2007-name-error)

Comment: I'll try to figure out how to open a VBA code window (in Access 2007 Runtime) to check for a missing library. Not sure that's possible.  How would one know which library is required for a date, or add a library?

Comment: I would check out the other link I posted where someone had a similar question. I bet that will resolve your issue. If that doesn't work, then try to check the library.